# INSERT INTO multiple tables from SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `GoodsInOld` which contains 4 columns:

```
GoodsInOld:     Id, CustomerAccount, CustomerName, ItemId
```

due to a new data structure I've created 2 new tables to hold the data:

`GoodsIn` and `GoodsInProduct`.

They have a relationship like below:

```
GoodsIn:        Id, CustomerAccount, CustomerName ...
GoodsInProduct: Id, ItemId, GoodsInId ...
```

`GoodsIn` MAY have 1 or many `GoodsInProduct`

I want to insert the data from `GoodsInOld` into these 2 tables using a `INSERT INTO` or `SELECT INTO`?

Comment: You could always use SSIS to move the data. Then you can use a Multi cast operator to split your results to as many tables as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into GoodsIn (CustomerAccount, CustomerName)
select CustomerAccount, CustomerName
from GoodsInOld 


insert into GoodsInProduct(ItemId, GoodsInId)
select o.ItemId, i.id
from GoodsInOld o
inner join GoodsIn i on o.CustomerAccount = i.CustomerAccount
                     and o.CustomerName = i.CustomerName
```

Comment: You may also want to select distinct from GoodsInOld for your customer info to go into GoodsIn if your original table could have duplicates.